# How to grow a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

The following demo code:

```
mydict = {}
mylist = []

mydict["s"] = 1
mydict["p"] = "hasprice"
mydict["o"] = 3
print(mydict)
mylist.append(mydict)

mydict["s"] = 22
mydict["p"] = "hasvat"
mydict["o"] = 66
print(mydict)
mylist.append(mydict)

print(mylist)
```

prints out the following result:

```
[{'s': 22, 'p': 'hasvat', 'o': 66}, {'s': 22, 'p': 'hasvat', 'o': 66}]
```

and the only explanation that comes to my mind is that mydict is assigned by reference and therefore the list items all point to a same memory object. Is this the reason?

How can I properly append multiple different dictionaries to the list?

I am building each mydict dictionary within a loop and then wanted to append it to the list which I will finally write to a JSON file.

Comment: Correct. The list contains the same dict object twice.

Comment: If like your example the keys are the same for each dictionary, you could write a function which takes the values as parameters and constructs a new dictionary with the common keys and new values. Something like `make_dict(22,"hasvat",66)`. As an added benefit this will avoid the aliasing problem that you are facing.

Comment: The `id` function is a good function for testing if two things point to the same object. Evaluating `id(mydict[0])` and `id(mydict[1])` would have confirmed your correct suspicion that the list items point to the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mylist.append(mydict)
```

So, what are you doing here? You're appending a `dict` object, right?

The problem is that in Python the `dict` is a mutable type, which gets passed by reference.

That's why when you edit `mydict` you're also editing `mylist[0]`, because they both reference to the same object.

---

To achieve what I think you want to do, simply do this instead:

```
mylist.append(mydict.copy())
```

This creates a copy which no more refers to `mydict`.

The copy should be done when first calling `.append`, otherwise you'll anyway get two identical `dict`s, as @sj95126 pointed out.

---

To better understand my answer, I strongly suggest to read the following:

- [STDTypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)
- [Mutable vs Immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types)
- [Python Mutable objects](https://towardsdatascience.com/https-towardsdatascience-com-python-basics-mutable-vs-immutable-objects-829a0cb1530a)

Comment: Might want to clarify whether you're copying the dict in the first `append()` or the second. In the second `append()` the values have already been changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very clear and also instructive. I prefer this solution since in my application mydict["s"] is initialized to a long complex hash which never changes, only p and o do change.

Answer (score 2):

```
mydict = {}
mylist = []

mydict["s"] = 1
mydict["p"] = "hasprice"
mydict["o"] = 3
print(mydict)
mylist.append(mydict)

mydict = {}  # This is a second dictionary

mydict["s"] = 22
mydict["p"] = "hasvat"
mydict["o"] = 66
print(mydict)
mylist.append(mydict)

print(mylist)
```

You'll get:

`[{'s': 1, 'p': 'hasprice', 'o': 3}, {'s': 22, 'p': 'hasvat', 'o': 66}]`

Comment: Thank you very much David. So the new initialization does allocate a new memory space, right? Very clear. I upvoted your simpler solution but chose FLAK's as the reply since in my real application the first member of the dictionary is initialized to a long hash that never changes and I don't have to reassign it each time in the loop.